# R Best way to delete data.table rows in a function call

Tags: r, data.table

I am looking for the best way to subset `iris` dataset in a function call. Here is the code -

```
data(iris)

remove_rows <- function(x)
{
  x = setDT(x)[Species == "virginica"]
}
remove_rows(iris)
> iris
     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
  1:          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    setosa
  2:          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    setosa
  3:          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    setosa
  4:          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    setosa
  5:          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    setosa
 ---                                                            
146:          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3 virginica
147:          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9 virginica
148:          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0 virginica
149:          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3 virginica
150:          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8 virginica
```

As you can see, none of the rows are deleted after running `remove_rows` function. This is understandable as library `data.table` does not have the functionality to remove rows by reference.
The workaround I have used is to update `remove_rows` function and return the new object from the function -

```
library(data.table)
remove_rows <- function(x)
{
  x= setDT(x)[Species == "virginica"]
  return(x)
}
iris = remove_rows(iris)
```

This has solved the problem, but since this data.table is huge in my case (iris is just a toy example), it takes a lot of time to run this function and copy the subset in iris dataset.

Is there a workaround to this situation?

Comment: You mind find this discussion helpful: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/635

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not yet implemented feature. Highly requested. You can track its progress in https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/635

Function `setsubset` that you are about to test is not complete. It lacks the C part to set true length of object to a shorter than the original, so without actually adding that missing piece, it won't help you much. As is now, it will return a subset at the beginning of the data.table and remaining rows will be garbage.

For now you have to return new object from a function and assign it to (possibly) same variable as the one you are passing to the function. If you really don't want to do this you can always use `assign` to parent frame, but it is less elegant.